# regex in sublime text for change [0-9]th

Tags: sublimetext2

In my several pages I'd like to change all

```
43th 
12th
```

in UTF-8 code

```
43&th;
12&th;
```

how can I do this in sublime text 2 using regex?

Thanks in advance

Luca

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find the element, you can use a regular expression like this:

```
([0-9][0-9])th
```

Then replace with:

```
$1&th;
```

[image]